# How can I calculate the day of week for a date in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

How can I write a method in Java, that will tell me the day of the week when I type in the date in the format `computeDayOfWeek(Month, Date)`?

Comment: You have tagged this with javascript, but asked for how to get the day of week in java, what is it you really want?

Comment: Homework? If so, please tag appropriately.

Comment: not homework, the basic java class I am in is just pictures and the turtles, this is extra credit. The instructions are... Write a method called computeDayOfWeek having two parameters a month and a day in the month (assume it is this year). It returns the day of the week that day is, where 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc. Your program should display the actual day of the week

Answer (score 2):

No need for external libraries. `java.util.Calendar` class handles those stuff.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(put a java.util.Date instance here);
int dow = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //1=sunday, 2=monday, 3=Calendar.WEDNESDAY...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking in Java. You can use the Joda-Time API to achieve this:
Check the documentation here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html

**Example**:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime()
System.out.println(dt.dayOfWeek().getAsText());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate this yourself instead of using a pre-made library function, have a look at [Zeller's congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

I implemented this last year, and then corrected about 40 solutions from students (first real program for quite some of them) trying to do their own - there are lots of ways to make mistakes here.  Make sure you test if for different dates (january, february, other months, normal years, leap years, year 2000 (is leap year) and 1900 (is no leap year)).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a fun little class some 10 years ago. I just made it for fun and never used it, but feel free to use and improve it as you please (mail me improvements). Pretty horrific code as I was a beginner then.

```
package se.danero.calendar.util;

import java.lang.NullPointerException;

/**
 * This is a Calendar that is meant to be used as a utility. To come up with this class, I analyzed the gregorian calendar, and I searched the web for
 * useful, free algorithms. Then I put them together to create this version of of the Calendar.<BR>
 * <BR>
 * <B>The analyze</B><BR>
 * In my analyze of the gregorian calendar, I have come to the conclution that<BR>
 * there are 8 different types of year endings. These endings have a recurring<BR>
 * cycle of 28 years. The pattern repeats itself over 28 years, continiously.<BR>
 * <BR>
 * The pattern consists of 8 different types of year-endings. These are listed below <BR>
 * <BR>
 * <B>Type</B><BR>
 * 1 = 4 times over a period of 28 year period<BR>
 * 2 = 4 times over a period of 28 year period<BR>
 * 3 = 3 times ... <BR>
 * 4 = 4 times ... <BR>
 * 5 = 4 times ... <BR>
 * 6 = 4 times ... <BR>
 * 7 = 4 times ... <BR>
 * 8 = 1 time ... <BR>
 * <BR>
 * 
 * @author Robert Nordin, robert.nordin@bredband.net
 * @version 0.5
 * 
 */
public class Calendar {
    // ****************************************************************************
    // *** MEMBERS
    // ****************************************************************************
    // *** Type of year break; beginning with break 1980/1981 ***
    private final int types[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 1, 8, 4, 7, 5 };

    // *** Week of the last week of the year and the first week of the new year ***
    private final int weeks[][] = { { 52, 1 }, { 52, 53 }, { 52, 1 }, { 52, 1 }, { 52, 1 }, { 52, 1 }, { 52, 1 }, { 52, 53 } };

    // Date of the last day of the last week and the last date of the first
    // week in the new year
    // private final int dates[][] = {{28, 4}, {27, 3}, { 2, 9}, { 1, 8},
    // {30, 6}, {29, 5}, {31, 7}, {26, 2}};

    private boolean initiated = false;
    private int year = 0;
    private int preMonths = 0;
    private int aftMonths = 0;

    // ****************************************************************************
    // *** CONSTRUCTORS
    // ****************************************************************************
    public Calendar() {
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    public Calendar(int year) throws OutOfRangeException {
        if (!isYearValid(year)) {
            throw new OutOfRangeException(OutOfRangeException.TYPE_YEAR, "Year[" + year + "]");
        } else {
            this.year = year;
            initiated = true;
        }
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    public Calendar(int year, int preMonths, int aftMonths) throws OutOfRangeException {
        if (!isYearValid(year)) {
            throw new OutOfRangeException(OutOfRangeException.TYPE_YEAR, "Year[" + year + "]");
        } else {
            this.year = year;
            initiated = true;
        }
        this.preMonths = ((preMonths >= 0) && (preMonths <= 12)) ? preMonths : 0;
        this.aftMonths = ((aftMonths >= 0) && (aftMonths <= 12)) ? aftMonths : 0;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    private boolean isYearValid(int year) {
        return ((year >= Date.MIN_YEAR) && (year <= Date.MAX_YEAR)) ? true : false;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    private int[] getWeeks(int type) {
        int retval[] = null;
        int arrayindex = type - 1;
        try {
            retval = weeks[arrayindex];
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("getWeeks(): Type is not inside valid range");
        }
        return retval;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    private int getType(int index) {
        int retval = types[index];
        if ((retval < 1) || (retval > 8)) {
            System.err.println("getType(): Index is not inside valid range");
        }
        return retval;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    private int getFirstWeek(int type) {
        int retval = 1;
        if (type == 3 || type == 4) {
            retval = 52;
        } else
            if (type == 2 || type == 8) {
                retval = 53;
            }
        return retval;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    private int getLastWeek(int type) {
        int retval = 52;
        if (type == 1 || type == 5 || type == 6) {
            retval = 1;
        } else
            if (type == 2 || type == 8) {
                retval = 53;
            }
        return retval;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    public String intToWeekday(int day, boolean longVersion) {
        String retval = "";
        /*
        if (day == 1) {
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Monday" : "Mon";
        } else
            if (day == 2) {
                retval = (longVersion) ? "Tuesday" : "Tue";
            } else
                if (day == 3) {
                    retval = (longVersion) ? "Wednesday" : "Wed";
                } else
                    if (day == 4) {
                        retval = (longVersion) ? "Thursday" : "Thu";
                    } else
                        if (day == 5) {
                            retval = (longVersion) ? "Friday" : "Fri";
                        } else
                            if (day == 6) {
                                retval = (longVersion) ? "Saturday" : "Sat";
                            } else
                                if (day == 7) {
                                    retval = (longVersion) ? "Sunday" : "Sun";
                                } else {
                                    System.err.println("intToWeekday(): Day is not inside valid range");
                                }
         */
        switch (day) {
        case 1: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Monday" : "Mon";
            break;
        case 2: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Tuesday" : "Tue";
            break;
        case 3: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Wednesday" : "Wed";
            break;
        case 4: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Thursday" : "Thu";
            break;
        case 5: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Friday" : "Fri";
            break;
        case 6: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Saturday" : "Sat";
            break;
        case 7: 
            retval = (longVersion) ? "Sunday" : "Sun";
            break;
        default: 
            System.err.println("intToWeekday(): Day is not inside valid range");
        }           
        return retval;
    }

    // ****************************************************************************
    private int getYearType(int year) {
        int retval = -1;
        if (year >= 1980) {
            retval = getType(((year - 1980) % 28));
        } else
            if (year == 1979) {
                retval = 5;
            } else {
                System.err.println("getYearType(): Year is not inside valid range");
            }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Compute the sequential number of a day in the year (1-Jan=1, 31-Dec=365/366). The algorithm used: J.D. Robertson: Remark on Algorithm 398,
     * Comm. ACM 13, 10 (Oct. 1972), p. 918
     * 
     * @param date
     *            a date of the day you query about
     * @return returns an integer between 1 and 365/366. 366 if it is a leapyear.
     * @throw NullPointerException if the date is null.
     */
    public int getDayInYear(Date date) throws NullPointerException {
        if (date == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Date cannot be null");
        int y = date.getYear();
        int m = date.getMonth();
        int d = date.getDay();
        int lm = (m + 10) / 13;
        return (int) (((long) 3055 * (long) (m + 2)) / 100 - 2 * lm - 91
                + (1 - (y - (y / 4) * 4 + 3) / 4 + (y - (y / 100) * 100 + 99) / 100 - (y - (y / 400) * 400 + 399) / 400) * lm + d);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of dates that conforms to a year and a week.
     * 
     * @param year
     *            the year in the form eg. 1980. Must be within Date.MIN_YEAR and Date.MAX_YEAR.
     * @param week
     *            the week. Must be less than 54
     * @return returns a full week of valid ISODates if inparameters are within the given range. returns a full week of null pointers if not.
     */
    public Date[] getWeekDates(int year, int week) {
        Date retval[] = new Date[7];
        if ((isYearValid(year)) && ((week > 0) && (week < 54))) {
            int dayCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= Date.getDaysInMonth(year, i); j++) {
                    Date tmp = new Date(year, i, j);

                    if (this.getWeekNumber(tmp) == week) {
                        retval[dayCounter] = tmp;
                        if (dayCounter == 7) {
                            i = 13;
                            j = 31;
                        }
                        if (dayCounter < 6) {
                            dayCounter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the weeknumber of the given date.
     * 
     * @param date
     *            a date that you want to know in what week it is.
     * @return returns the weeknumber as an integer.
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *             if the parameter is null.
     */
    public int getWeekNumber(Date date) throws NullPointerException {
        int retval = -1;
        if (date == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("ISODate cannot be null");
        // *** Incoming data ***
        int year = date.getYear();
        int month = date.getMonth();
        int day = date.getDay();

        if (isYearValid(year)) {
            int targetDay = getDayInYear(date);
            int firstWeek = getFirstWeek(getYearType((year - 1)));
            int lastWeek = getLastWeek(getYearType(year));
            Date oneone = new Date(year, 1, 1);

            int firstDay = getDayInWeek(oneone);
            int dayCounter = 0;
            int weekCounter = firstWeek;
            int dayInWeek = firstDay;

            while (dayCounter != targetDay) {
                if (dayInWeek == 8) {
                    dayInWeek = 1;
                    if ((weekCounter > 51) && (dayCounter < 10)) {
                        weekCounter = 1;
                    } else
                        if ((dayCounter > 360) && (weekCounter > lastWeek)) {
                            weekCounter = lastWeek;
                        } else {
                            weekCounter++;
                        }
                }
                dayCounter++;
                dayInWeek++;
            }
            retval = weekCounter;
        }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an integer that tells you what day of the week the date specifies. The algorithm used is Zeller's congruence for the Gregorian
     * calendar.
     * 
     * @param date
     *            a date that points out the day you want to know the weekday of.
     * 
     * @return returns the weekday in the form of an integer. 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday...
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *             if the parameter is null.
     */
    public int getDayInWeek(Date date) throws NullPointerException {
        if (date == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("ISODate cannot be null");
        int year = date.getYear();
        int month = date.getMonth();
        int day = date.getDay();
        if (month < 3) {
            month += 12;
            year--;
        }
        return ((13 * month + 3) / 5 + day + year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400) % 7 + 1;
    }
}
```